# Admob Policy: Is it allowed to set Ad Unit ID/size from server response?

Tags: android, admob, policy

I would like set Ad Unit ID and size from a response of my server (without Firebase) because, i realized after few days revenue becomes lower and also i would like make some tests between size "BANNER" and "SMART_BANNER".

After checking, admob policy, i dint see anything relevant about this topic, just want be sure it's allowed by admob or not ? (support doesn't answer...)

Thanks

Comment: For adding Admob layout you have to use in XML to add `SMART_BANNER` but I don't think it allowed in Java or kotlin code.

Comment: Yes its possible to set the size by Java or Kotlin, my question is more about seting it from outside of the app specialy the id

Comment: adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
adView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use that!

Simply request you server for the Ad type (BANNER/SMART_BANNER) before requesting an Ad and add `adView.adSize = sizeFromServer`

Additionally, you’ll have to create the `AdView` object programmatically and add it to your `ViewGroup` because `AdView` parameters/arguments like adSize, adUnits, defined in xml cannot be changed.

Tip: `SMART_BANNER` is more effective than `BANNER`.

Comment: Tanks for your answer, what about if i just dont set the size and unit on the xml, dont need to add it to the viewgroup in that case ?

Comment: It still won't work, once adView is set in XML, it cannot be changed programmatically, also if you go for XML then you have to set the AdSize and AdUnitId, else it will crash. Its better to create `AdView` programmatically  and add it in the `ViewGroup`